# Azure compute gallery sysprep issues

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, sysprep

I am trying to update an Azure Compute Gallery version but it's not working properly.
The process I am following is as follows:

1. Deploy the old version from the Compute Gallery to a new VM and start.
2. Use RDP to login to VM and patch. The OS is Windows Server 2019. Its an application server with a single drive so basically IIS and third party application.
3. VM is patched using Windows Update and updates are applied for .net updates. Basic security settings are tightened up (TLS1.0 and 1.1 disabled etc.)
4. Reboot etc. Test connectivity to the application - all good.
5. The fun starts here... run sysprep (sysprep.exe /oobe /generalize /mode:vm /shutdown)
6. System shuts down
7. Note the disk used in the VM and add a version in the Compute Gallery which points to the disk of the VM I just patched
8. Save Compute Gallery version
9. Attempt to test - from Compute Gallery deploy as new VM
10. The deploy never finishes. In the Azure console it sits at Creating indefinitely

This is driving me crazy. I have tried variations of the sysprep command line. I have tried different sized Azure servers. I have tested to see if there are any patches that are stuck in pending but nothing.

Does anyone have any ideas please?
Ganners

Answer (score 0):

I think I have worked this one out myself.

I'd created a new Compute Gallery for the stuff I was creating and I'd inadvertently used a Windows v1 image definition rather than v2. It turns out the difference is all around UEFI compatibility/emulation. Created a new v2 gallery and image and hey presto it all works!